# How to check connectivity to a server IP

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app, which connects to the local network via wifi, so I need to validate that the device has the connection with the server to consume web services, and in case it has no connection notify the user of the error.
Is there any way to ping in a flutter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app

Comment: You may want to get some hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555914/run-flutter-app-only-if-internet-connection-is-available/55555933#55555933)